# Spring Tool Source (STS) - problem getting my first project compile

Tags: maven, spring-roo, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have been trying to create brand new Java Roo based project using STS 2.7.1 RELEASE. I choose to use Roo and Maven as default setting and after updating all the Maven dependencies from the Project menu (hence resolving the initial errors due to the missing dependendices defined automatically by STS in pom.xml file) I remain with the following JSP problem:

```
ErrorCMDocument_load_exception=An error occurred while loading document {0} with publicId {1}
```

in resource called: **load-scripts.tagx**

The problem is with the following two lines in the file load-script.tagx:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${tundra_url}"><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="${roo_css_url}"><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --></link>
```

I am not sure if there is any configuration problem or what else.. would anyone be able to suggest some solution?

Many thanks and Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

See [this POST from the Spring Roo forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?111961-Roo-%281.1.5%29-generated-proj-s-have-missing-style-sheets)

You can find a temporary solution (POST at July 19th, 2011 04:38 PM)